# Formatting XSL Date Value to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: xslt

XLT formatting a date field...

I have the following XLT in my custom sharepoint list application

```
<td class="style21" style="width: 185px" ><xsl:value-of select="@app_pr_datesub" /></td>
```

**which produces**

> 2018-03-25T04:00:00Z

How do I format that as
 **03/25/2018**

Comment: You forgot to write the code

Comment: XSLT questions should always say which version of XSLT you are using, as this very often affects the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@app_pr_datesub) ,1033 ,1)" />
```

This worked for me and posted as mm/dd/yyyy